# Do you know any exact information about "marriage" terms?

Tags: past-tense, passive-voice

What is the difference between:

> they were married
>   they got married
>   they married?

Would you, considering what you say about these terms, tell me how to use these terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SHORT ANSWER:
In most uses these three mean the same thing. *They got married* is conversational, *They were married* is what you should use in writing, and *They married* is an uncommon expression you might use in a novel or biography.

They have other uses, which are explained below.

LONGER ANSWER:
These three expressions *may* mean exactly the same thing; when they do, they mark different registers:

- *They were married* is the ordinary **formal** usage. It is a passive construction, and means that somebody (a priest or a magistrate) officially carried out the ceremony which made them man and wife.
- *They got married* is an informal or **colloquial** usage, employing the so-called ‘*get* passive’, which substitutes *get* for *be*.
- *They married* is a **literary** usage: it is an active rather than passive form and depicts  the bride and groom as the parties who caused the event to happpen.

This is the only meaning which *get married* may have. The other two forms, however, may have different meanings in different contexts.

- *Be married* may describe a status rather than an event. For instance, you might say

  > In 1993 I met Bob and Helen. They were married, and had two children.

  In this case, the past participle *married* has lost the sense of being a verb and has become an adjective: we speak of *a married couple* or *a married man*.
- *Marry* as an active verb is usually transitive, meaning to join two things, in either a literal or a figurative sense:

  > Father Peter married Bob and Helen at the Old Cathedral.
  >   Technicians married the filter unit to the outfall pipe.
  >   Chefs Roget and Phong formed an innovative partnership: they married traditional French techniques with Southeast Asian ingredients.

Comment: More discussion of the so-called ‘*get* passive’ can be found on [our sister site, EL&U](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/143448).

Answer (score -1):

They were married (Past Tense). Means in the past they married.
e.g They were married couple when i met them.

They Got married(Simple Present). Means They have married.
e.g. They Got married on 31st December.

They Married(Simple Present). Means Simply they are married.
e.g They Married each other on 31st December